# Python Riemann Sum does not yield zero for equal positive and negative areas

Tags: python, matplotlib, integral, calculus

I wrote a program to approximate an integral using a Riemann sum and graph it using matplotlib in Python. For functions with equal areas above and below the x-axis, the resulting area should be zero, but my program outputs a very small number instead.

The following code graphs the odd function f(x) = x^3 from -1 to 1, so the area should be zero. My code instead approximates it to be 1.68065561477562 e^-15.

What is causing this? Is it a rounding error in delta_x, x, or y? I know I could just round the value to zero, but I'm wondering if there is another problem or way to solve this.

I have tried using the Decimal.decimal class for delta_x, but I just got an even smaller number.

The Python code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Approximates and graphs integral using Riemann Sum


# example function: f(x) = x^3
def f_x(x):
    return x**3

# integration range from a to b with n rectangles
a, b, n = -1, 1, 1000

# calculate delta x, list of x-values, list of y-values, and approximate area under curve
delta_x = (b - a) / n

x = np.arange(a, b+delta_x, delta_x)

y = [f_x(i) for i in x]

area = sum(y) * delta_x

# graph using matplotlib
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.bar(x, y, delta_x, alpha=.5)
plt.title('a={}, b={}, n={}'.format(a, b, n))
plt.xlabel('A = {}'.format(area))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be aware that what you are computing is not a Riemann integral in the original sense. You are dividing the interval into `n` bins, but then sum over `n+1` bins (here `n = 1000` but `len(x) == 1001`). So the result may be close to what you expect, but it is certainly not a good way to get there.

Using the [Riemann sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum) you would divide your interval into `n` bins, and then sum over the values of those `n` bins. You have the choice whether to compute the left Riemann sum, the right Riemann sum, or possibly taking the midpoints.

```
import numpy as np

def f_x(x):
    return x**3

# integration range from a to b with n rectangles
a, b, n = -1, 1, 1000

delta_x = (b - a) / float(n)

x_left = np.arange(a, b, delta_x)
x_right = np.arange(a+delta_x, b+delta_x, delta_x)
x_mid = np.arange(a+delta_x/2., b+delta_x/2., delta_x)

print len(x_left),  len(x_right), len(x_mid)          ### 1000 1000 1000


area_left = f_x(x_left).sum() * delta_x
area_right = f_x(x_right).sum() * delta_x
area_mid = f_x(x_mid).sum() * delta_x

print area_left     # -0.002
print area_right    #  0.002
print area_mid      # 1.81898940355e-15
```

While the midpoint sum already gives a good result, for symmetric functions it would be a good idea to choose `n` even, and take the average of the left and right sum,

```
print 0.5*(area_right+area_left)   # 1.76204537072e-15
```

This is equally close to 0.

Now it is worthwhile noting that `numpy.arange` produces some errors by itself. A better choice would be using `numpy.linspace`

```
x_left = np.linspace(a, b-delta_x, n)
x_right = np.linspace(a+delta_x, b, n)
x_mid = np.linspace(a+delta_x/2., b-delta_x/2., n)
```

yielding

```
print area_left     # -0.002
print area_right    #  0.002
print area_mid      # 8.52651282912e-17
print 0.5*(area_right+area_left)   # 5.68121938382e-17
```

`5.68121938382e-17` is pretty close to 0. The reason why it is not entirely 0 is indeed [floating point inaccuracies](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).

The famous example of that would be 
`0.1 + 0.2 - 0.3`
which results in `5.5e-17` instead of 0. This is to show that this simply operation introduces the same error of the order of 1e-17 as the Riemann integration.

Comment: Yeah, funnily enough if you only ever use an odd number of subintervals, then taking the left Riemann sum over `-1` to `1+delta_x` is equivalent to using the midpoint approximation for an interval over `-1-delta_x/2` to `1+delta_x/2` and so stays symmetric.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is just due to floating point inaccuracy.

For constructing the partition, [`np.linspace()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) may be more appropriate since [`np.arange()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) may or may not include the endpoint depending on how it's rounded when using non-integer step sizes.

**From [numpy.arange()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) documentation:**

> When using a non-integer step, such as 0.1, the results will often not be consistent. It is better to use linspace for these cases.

Comment: This is in principle correct, although the code from the question has another flaw that is more severe than the accuracy discussed here. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be valid to me. It sums the `y` returned by `f_x`, and accounts for the approximation error of having only 1000 subintervals by adding `delta_x` to the second argument of `arange`. Unfortunately, I think that roundoff error is at play here.